# How to transform array of arrays into an array of objects with Ramda?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

### Background

I have an array of arrays that represents a grid with the following format:

```
const grid = [
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, "®" , null, null, null, null, "®" ],
    ["©" , "©" , null, null, "©" , "®" , "®" ],
    ["®" , "®" , "®" , "©" , "®" , "©" , "©" ],
    ["®" , "©" , "©" , "®" , "©" , "®" , "©" ],
];
```

### Objective

My objective is to transform that array into the following:

```
const grid = [ 
    { row: 0, column: 1, value: null},
    { row: 0, column: 2, value: null},
    { row: 0, column: 3, value: null},
    //... some rows after ...
    { row: 3, column: 0, value: "©"},
    // etc...
];
```

### Research

My first idea was to use two nested `R.map`and the `R.chain` it.  However I have a major problem: The ramda functions do *not* take indexes as parameters ( unlike the counter implementations in JavaScript ).

So I believe that doing this exercise using ramda, is not possible.

### Question

Is there a way to do this exercise using only ramda functions ( no for loops ) ?

Comment: Did you consider using vanilla JS? I don't know ramda, but I'm pretty sure you can get a clean functionnal version with vanilla JS to get your expected output.

Comment: If the problem is the missing indexes, I think https://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#addIndex will be able to help by decorating with the indexes you need? Most functional languages have similar capabilities, like `zipWithIndex` in Scala.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ramda but it has also [mapObjIndexed](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mapObjIndexed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Using the solution from @sjahan The natural solution using Ramda is as follow:

```
const R  require("ramda");
const mapIndexed = R.addIndex( R.map );
const reduceIndexed = R.addIndex( R.reduce );

const convertGrid = reduceIndexed(
  ( acc, array, i ) => [...acc, ...mapIndexed( ( value, j ) => ( { row: i, column: j, value } ), array ) ],
  [ ]
);
```

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in comments: here is a version without ramda, but also without any for loop.

Hope you'll like it ;)

As you can see, it's totally possible to do this without any for loop, and without any overlay like ramda or another lib.

```js
const grid = [
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, "®" , null, null, null, null, "®" ],
    ["©" , "©" , null, null, "©" , "®" , "®" ],
    ["®" , "®" , "®" , "©" , "®" , "©" , "©" ],
    ["®" , "©" , "©" , "®" , "©" , "®" , "©" ],
];

const result = grid.reduce((r, array, i) => [...r, ...array.map((value, j) => ({row: i, column: j, value}))], []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am very well aware of the possibility of doing it without ramda. That was not the question. The challenge is in using it :P

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using Ramda is to map over the rows to add their column index, then [`transpose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#transpose) the grid, then map over it again to add row index to each column.

```js
const grid = [
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, "®" , null, null, null, null, "®" ],
    ["©" , "©" , null, null, "©" , "®" , "®" ],
    ["®" , "®" , "®" , "©" , "®" , "©" , "©" ],
    ["®" , "©" , "©" , "®" , "©" , "®" , "©" ],
];

const mapCol = R.addIndex(R.map)(R.flip(R.assoc('column')))
const mapRow = R.addIndex(R.map)(R.flip(R.assoc('row')))
const mapVal = R.map(R.objOf('value'))

const fn = R.pipe(
  R.map(mapVal),  // convert each value to `{ value: ... }`
  R.map(mapCol),  // add the column index `{ value: ..., column: n }`
  R.transpose,    // transpose the whole grid
  R.chain(mapRow) // add the row index `{ value: ..., column: n, row: m }`
)

console.log(fn(grid))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

The last call to [`R.chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) just takes care of mapping and flattening in a single step.

Note that this results in a list ascending by column then row. If you need the list ascending by row then column as per your example, you could transpose the grid again like so:

```
const fn = pipe(
  R.map(mapVal),
  R.map(mapCol),
  R.transpose,
  R.map(mapRow),
  R.transpose,
  R.unnest
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested loop does it:

```
 const result = [];

 for(const [row, content] of grid.entries()) {
    for(const [column, value] of content.entries()) {
       result.push({ row, column, value });
    }
}
```

Comment: Allow me to re-iterate the questions being asked: _Is there a way to do this exercise using only ramda functions ( **no for loops** ) ?_